# Flaky code rendering bug

Tags: bug

[This version of my answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/revisions/294134/2) didn't render correctly. I ran into the problem several times when trying to write the post, where SE would only display {{content.field.caption}} instead of the whole code block. Also, the incomplete output is formatted text when this bug occurs rather than fixed-width code style.

It's reproducible in this post, just delete the blank line after "The whole code block is:"

The whole code block is:

```
<figure>
  <img src="{{ file_url(content.field_image['#items'].entity.uri.value) }}"/>
  <figcaption>{{ content.field_caption }}</figcaption>
</figure>
```